# sending an object's property as parameter to a function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am getting myself into javascript/jQuery and therefore am building a Plant vs Zombies. I created an object for the enemies and create a reference for each enemy that shows up with that code:
This is the object:

```
var Enemy = function(row, num) {
    'use strict';
    this.row = row;
    this.number = num; 
    this.move_interval;
    this.html_element;
};
Enemy.prototype.create = function() {
    this.html_element = $('<div class="enemy '+this.row+' full" style="left:1140px;top: '+$('tr.row_'+this.row).position().top+'px"></div>').prependTo('.container');

    return this;
};
Enemy.prototype.die = function() {
    clearInterval(this.move_interval);
    this.html_element.remove();
    return this;
};
Enemy.prototype.move = function() {
    this.move_interval = setInterval(function() {moveEnemy(this.number)}, 2000);
    return this;
};
```

this is the interval for creating an enemy (i is defined as global variable "var i = 0;"):

```
enemy_interval = setInterval("addEnemy(i++)", 9000)}
```

this is the function to create an Enemy (the random-thingy is because i have four rows on which the enemy could spawn on, thats also what the property row in the object is for):

```
function addEnemy(num) {
    if (num < 5) {
        switch (getRandom(1,4)) {
            case 1:
                enemies[num] = new Enemy("one", num);
                enemies[num].create().move();
                break;
            case 2:
                enemies[num] = new Enemy("two", num)
                enemies[num].create().move();
                break;
            case 3:
                enemies[num] = new Enemy("three", num)
                enemies[num].create().move();
                break;
            case 4:
                enemies[num] = new Enemy("four", num)
                enemies[num].create().move();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is where the error is showing up:

```
function moveEnemy(number) {
    enemies[number].html_element.animate({left: "-=150"}, 2000, "linear");
}
```

I have tried several ways by editing the moveEnemy function to get the property "html_element" as parameter and doing it that way:

```
function moveEnemy(obj) {
    obj.animate({left: "-=150"}, 2000, "linear");
}
```

I have tried to write it like enemies[number][html_element] because i read thats actually the way to get a property but it didn't work as well. It is always telling me that the parameter ('obj' or as above 'number' is undefined).

Is anyone able to see that mistake? D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your `setInterval` function, where scope has changed, and `this` has become the global (window) object.

change your `move` function to this:

```
Enemy.prototype.move = function() {
    var me = this;
    this.move_interval = setInterval(function() {moveEnemy(me.number)}, 2000);
    return this;
};
```

Comment: jsFiddle with the above fix works http://jsfiddle.net/A4UUy/1/ figured id post the fiddle as id already made it.